# What is transparent class or transparent method in C#?`

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have C# code and when I run FXCop against it, it yields a strange error which I tried to understand but I couldn't. The error says

> Transparent Methods Must Not Satisfy Link Demands.

Here what I don't understand is what is a **transparent method**? When going though the MSDN help I came across a term called **transparent class**.

Can anyone please explain me what **transparent class** or **transparent mehod** mean?

Comment: Post the link to the MSDN docs you're talking about.

Comment: And post the code that gives this warning

Comment: MSDN knows it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997445.aspx . Seems clear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from msdn page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191569(v=vs.110).aspx

> Transparency is an enforcement mechanism that separates code that runs
>   as part of the application from code that runs as part of the
>   infrastructure. Transparency draws a barrier between code that can do
>   privileged things (critical code), such as calling native code, **and
>   code that cannot (transparent code)**. Transparent code can execute
>   commands within the bounds of the permission set it is operating in,
>   but cannot execute, derive from, or contain critical code.

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your quick answer.